# The Android App likes to play "catch up" with notifications I've already seen

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, android-app

My phone has spent the past five minutes vibrating off of my desk as it played "catch up" on a bunch of notifications that I had dismissed on-site before my phone had a chance to notify me of them in the status bar.

My phone notifies me just fine of regular notifications that I haven't checked yet, and checking them in the app or on the site dismisses them properly in both places. However, notifications that get almost immediately dismissed because I'm currently active on-site never make it to my phone... **until**...

Some time later when there's a mass amount of these notifications which my phone has never seen, the app starts notifying me of them one-by-one, vibrating each time as if I had received a new notification. Sometimes it vibrates and pops up an icon, and then immediately realizes I had already seen the notification and goes away, sometimes it makes me actually dismiss the notification manually. In all cases, the notifications start popping up in *reverse order* of which they occurred, in random spots in between notifications that had already been properly dismissed.

Can this phenomenon please be fixed? It's rather irritating to be sitting somewhere and all of a sudden get notified of 10 or 20 different things that I've already seen.

[image]

Comment: Same here. Thankfully I disabled vibrate before hand. But possibly related to the [ongoing SQL woes](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/68070366322/projected-outages-update-november-25-2013)?

Comment: @StevenV I doubt it. I experienced this about a week ago too, just never got around to reporting it until now. Unless those issues have been going on for that long...

Comment: Never mind then! My phone just threw up a bunch of push notifications in the last few minutes that I read on the site ealier. Kind of just wrote them off because of the issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there was a direct correlation between our SQL issues and the push notification service issues.  I restarted it about an hour ago and adding a throttle is a good idea.  I'll add that to the list of features we intend to build.