# The Android App is still playing catch up, but it catches itself mid-notification

Tags: bug, notifications, android-app

This is a bit of a continuation off of my [previous bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208968/the-android-app-likes-to-play-catch-up-with-notifications-ive-already-seen).

The problem I've been experiencing is that after already having checked my notifications on-site and dismissing them, the Android App is still having trouble keeping up with what I've seen already. Whenever it does finally update with new notifications, it vibrates and starts the sound like a normal notification for a new item, and then immediately stops both as it finally realizes that I *have* already seen the notification.

Could this behavior be modified in any way so the notification never even *starts* if I've seen the notifications already? I can say it is obvious / easy to tell when this happens, because you get a very, very brief vibration and almost unnoticeable sound because the notification doesn't even last but a fraction of a second, but it *is* still noticeable and it'd be much more user-friendly if the notification never started to begin with.

Further, for a user who is not experienced with this problem, it could be quite confusing - wondering why their phone briefly started a notification, looking at their phone to see there's absolutely nothing there.

**An attempt at clarification.** Imagine this timeline of events:

1. App realizes it has new notifications.
2. App initiates notification in status bar on device (sound and vibrate, depending on device settings).
3. App realizes you've actually seen the notification(s) already.
4. App cancels device notification in the middle.

Comment: This explains a lot