# Months-old notifications suddenly coming in from the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, notifications

I am using version 1.0.66 of the Stack Exchange Android App. Yesterday I received a notification on my phone (1st gen. Moto G, running 4.4.4) about two inbox items. The inbox items in question are associated with [this comment reply](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196/aluminium-or-aluminum#comment437_197) and [this chat reply](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21101?m=20092635#20092635) (private room), both from Feb. 16 of this year. (For anyone keeping score, that's 142 days ago.)

When I tapped on the notification item, the app launched and showed my inbox with no unread messages. The oldest item there is from less than two weeks ago. (Click the images below for full resolution screenshots of the notification and the app inbox after tapping the notification.)

[image] [image]

I did have the app installed at the time these inbox items were generated. I may or may not have been notified by the app at the time; when I am actively reading a Stack site, I view the top-bar notification promptly, which seems to keep it from being pushed to the app. I have not had any other problems (that I have noticed) receiving notifications from the app recently.

Possibly related older bug reports include:

- [Stack Exchange Android app keeps replaying notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242988/254929) ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Nov. 2014)
- [The Android App likes to play "catch up" with notifications I've already seen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208968/254929) ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Nov. 2013)

This reoccurred later in the same day, albeit to a smaller degree, when my phone sent me a notification for a comment that was *merely* 6 hours old. In this case, I confidently recall receiving the notification in my desktop browser topbar, clicking through and leaving a comment reply, 6 hours ago.

Comment: Anyone knows that the latest release of Android App was invaded by evil.

Comment: @nicael [Is summoning undead evil?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/41663)

Comment: Duplicated here. I've been getting old notifications every 30 seconds for the last 1/2 hour :/

Comment: I guess there's a fix on SE API that triggered these old notifications when trying to fix the crashes on 1.0.66...